# In Big Sur, is there a way to increase the voice dictation timeout?

Tags: big-sur, voice-dictation

I enjoy using the voice dictation feature on Big Sur - it is very accurate and for me it is substantially quick than type.

Except it just cuts off after about 30 seconds.  Is there a way to increase the amount of time it stays active?

I see there's a similar question about OSX 10.8.